# Why isn't this function reading and displaying cookie?

Tags: javascript, function, cookies

I have written this code. But it isn't displaying cookie. It displays only **prompt** again and again, whenever I open this page. How can I correct it?

```
<body onload="myFunc()">

<script>
function createCookie(value, exdays)
{
    var date= new Date();
    var d= date.setTime(date.getDate()+(exdays*10000));
    var e = date.toUTCString(d);
    var g = document.cookie= "user="+value+";"+" "+"expires="+e;
    return g;
}
function readCookie()
{
    var h = document.cookie;
    var i= h.split(";");
    return i[0];
}


function myFunc()
{
    var a= readCookie();
    if(a!="")
    {
        alert("Welcome"+a);
    }
    else
    {
        var b = prompt("Enter your name", "");
        createCookie(b, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What does "it's not working" mean? Do you see the alert at all? If you look in the browser's error console, do you see error messages?

Comment: Calling `two` sets the cookie anew, because it calls `one` again. This might cause problems. Anyway, I can see the alert when clicking “Read”. Maybe you have disabled cookies in your browser.

Comment: If you have more than 1 cookie your `i[0]` will only display the first `key=value` pair.

Comment: My mistake. I tried in other browsers and it's displaying user=Vikas. But why isn't it displying this string in Chrome? The alert is displayed, but it's empty! I haven't disabled Cookies.

Comment: Well what is in `console.log(document.cookie)`

Comment: I use Chrome and your code works fine.

Comment: It is showing "2", in a sky blue colored circular background :P I wrote console.log(document.cookie) in place of alert.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson but I'm not lying :'(

Comment: @VikasKumar Never said you were, either. :)

Comment: Can you create a jsbin.com and show us your problem?

Comment: Change your line from `document.cookie="user=Vikas; expires=Sun, 18 Dec 2016 12:00:00 UTC";` to `document.cookie="user=Vikas; expires=Sun, 18 Dec 2016 12:00:00 GMT";`  and see if it works...

Comment: Ok. This problem is solved. Thanks to everyone. I shall help you one day. Now please check the EDIT. There's a new problem.

Comment: Can anybody solve the EDIT section problem?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney no errors after editing "date" to "Date()". But still it's not displaying cookie. It's showing prompt every time.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson Please solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript IS case sensitive:

```
var date = new Date();
```

Comment: Ok sir, but that doesn't solve my problem. I implore you to check EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Your snipped works fine in most browsers, even in chrome. Except you are working on your local file-system (URL = file:///xxx). Chrome has local file cookies on default disabled but you can activate them with command-parameters '--allow-file-cookies'.

Comment: Ok. This problem is solved. Now please check the EDIT. There's a new problem.